# How can I print debug info in custom module?

Tags: views, debugging

I need to edit parts of a custom module that I didn't make, and I don't really have much experience editing/coding custom modules. How do I print debug info in functions in a custom module?

In the custom module it overwrites the buildConditions function from Entity API QueryAccess, and I need to have the function add role-related conditions only if one of two views is being viewed but I don't know how to do that, and I can't figure out how to print debug info in the function that will show up on the page so I can figure out how to do what I need to do. Do any of y'all have an idea on how I can fix this?

Comment: Did you try kint() or var_dump() to see the values? They can help.

Comment: Yeah, neither of those prints to the page for this function

Comment: Sometimes I add die() function just after kint() or var_dump() so that the process stops there and prints the value inside kint or var_dump. Try it. If it doesn't work, then please paste the relevant part of your code so it is easier to help.